# Setting up SSL for node.js with a private key

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've setup our IIS server with SSL enabled. The certificate provided to us by our administrator contains only the .cer and .pfb files. I was able to configure IIS with just the cer file. However, for nodejs, from the internet searches that i've made, it seems that we need a private key (.key) to successfully setup the NodeJS with SSL. Is there anyway i can setup NodeJS with just the .cer or .pfb files?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure it is a `pfb` and not a `pfx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

1. Export the certificate on MMC. See this [link](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm) for more info:
2. Follow the procedure from this [link](https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Extracting+Certificate+and+Private+Key+Files+from+a+.pfx+File)

it will give you a certificate and the key.